# write result of for statement

Tags: python, list, lines

I'm very new to Python, and attempt to do the following

- read file,
- replace spaces with new lines,
- remove any line containing the ":" character
- write result to text file

So far I have got the following, I know there should be a o.write somewhere, however I've tried a bunch of different spots and nothing seems to work, I'm pretty sure I'm missing something simple.

```
import os

i = open("input.txt", "r+")
o = open("output.txt", "a+")

for line in i.readlines():
    (line.replace(" ", "\n"))
    if ":" in line:
        (line)


i.close()
o.close()
```

The input file is as follows

```
192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1 192.168.3.1 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So I have:**

**EDITED** to remove lines with a *:*

*test.txt*

```
192.168.1.1 192.168.2.1 192.168.3.1 2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334
```

*answer.py*

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()

lines = text.split(' ')
lines = [line for line in lines if ':' not in line]

with open('result.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

*result.txt*

```
192.168.1.1
192.168.2.1
192.168.3.1
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I wanted to remove the entire line that contains a ":"
That's insanely close

Comment: Ok, should be fixed now

Comment: I'm glad it's what you want. If you are not familiar with the statements I used, I suggest trying to find out what each one does.

Comment: @JamesSchinner A good place to start would be the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/).

Comment: @ChristianDean Yes, I agree, though admittedly. I found the `docs` intimidating when I first started. Sometimes being walked though it in a youtube clip can be quite useful.

Comment: That is true. Many people do learn better when be talked to by another person. On that note @Tom, one resource that I found particularly helpful when I was first learning to program was the [sentdex YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IX6mc9l6tY4).

Answer (score 0):

you can build your new file contents first and afterward write to it:

```
import os

i = open("in", "r+")
o = open("out", "a+")

result = ""

for line in i.readlines():
        if ":" not in line:
                result += line.replace(" ", "\n")


o.write(result)

i.close()
o.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

- Replaces the spaces with newlines *before* iterating over the file's contents. if you don't, then you'll only be iterating over a single line.
- There's no need for the `os` library in your code.
- Call `o.write(line)` after testing if the line has no colon(`:`).
- Use the context manger to do your I/O operations.
- Use more descriptive names than `i` and `o` to avoid writing confusing code.

With the above modifications, your code becomes:

```
with open("input.txt", "r+") as infile, open("output.txt", "a+") as outfile:
    contents = infile.read().replace(' ', '\n')
    for line in contents.split('\n'):
        if ':' not in line:
            outfile.write(line + '\n')
```